# Showing that $F$ is a monotone function

Tags: partial-order, data-flow-analysis, lattices, order-theory

I am currently studying the textbook [*Principles of Program Analysis* by Flemming Nielson, Hanne R. Nielson, and Chris Hankin](http://faculty.sist.shanghaitech.edu.cn/faculty/songfu/cav/PPA.pdf). Chapter **1.3 Data Flow Analysis** says the following:

> **The least solution.** The above system of equations defines the twelve sets
> $$\text{RD}_\text{entry}(1), \dots, \text{RD}_{\text{exit}}(6)$$
> in terms of each other. Writing $\overrightarrow{RD}$ for this twelve-tuple of sets we can regard the equation system as defining a function $F$ and demanding that:
> $$\overrightarrow{RD} = F(\overrightarrow{RD})$$
> To be more specific we can write
> $$F(\overrightarrow{RD}) (F_\text{entry}(1)(\overrightarrow{RD}), F_\text{exit}(1)(\overrightarrow{RD}), \dots, F_\text{entry}(6)(\overrightarrow{RD}), F_\text{exit}(6)(\overrightarrow{RD}))$$
> where e.g.:
> $$F_\text{entry}(3)(\dots, \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(2), \dots, \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(5), \dots) = \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \cup \overrightarrow{RD}_\text{exit}(5)$$
> It should be clear that $F$ operates over twelve-tuples of sets of pairs of variables and labels; this can be written as
> $F : (\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12} \to (\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$
> where it might be natural to take $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star} = \mathbf{\text{Var}}$ and $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star} = \mathbf{\text{Lab}}$. However, it will simplify the presentation in this chapter to let $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star}$ be a *finite* subset of $\mathbf{\text{Var}}$ that contains the variables occurring in the program $\mathbf{S_\star}$ of interest and similarly for $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}$. So for the example program we might have $\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star} = \{ x, y, z \}$ and $\mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star} = \{ 1, \dots, 6, ? \}$.
>
> It is immediate that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ can be partially ordered by setting
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime \ \ \ \text{iff} \ \ \ \forall i : \text{RD}_i \subseteq \text{RD}_i^\prime$$
> where $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} = (\text{RD}_1, \dots, \text{RD}_{12})$ and similarly $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime = (\text{RD}_1^\prime, \dots, \text{RD}_{12}^\prime)$. This turns $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{\text{Var}_\star \times \mathbf{\text{Lab}_\star}))}^{12}$ into a complete lattice (see Appendix A) with least element
> $$\overrightarrow{\emptyset} = (\emptyset, \dots, \emptyset)$$
> and binary least upper bounds given by:
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqcup \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime = (\text{RD}_1 \cup \text{RD}_1^\prime, \dots, \text{RD}_{12} \cup \text{RD}_{12}^\prime)$$
>
> It is easy to show that $F$ is in fact a monotone function (see Appendix A) meaning that:
> $$\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime \ \ \ \text{implies} \ \ \ F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}) \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})^\prime$$
> This involves calculations like
> $$\text{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \subseteq \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(2) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \text{RD}_\text{exit}(5) \subseteq \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(5)$$
> imply
> $$\text{RD}_\text{exit}(2) \cup \text{RD}_\text{exit}(5) \subseteq \text{RD}^\prime_\text{exit}(2) \cup \text{RD}_\text{exit}^\prime(5)$$
> and the details are left to the reader.

Appendix A gives the following definition for *monotone function*:

> The function $f$ is *monotone* (or *isotone* or *order-preserving*) if
> $$\forall l, l^\prime \in L_1 : l \sqsubseteq_1 l^\prime \Rightarrow f(l) \sqsubseteq_2 f(l^\prime)$$

From earlier in the textbook:

> [image]

> [image]

I am trying to do as the author said, and show that $F$ is a monotone function. However, I have so far been unable to make progress. It seems to me that such a proof should proceed by showing that, for some arbitrary element of the set of elements $F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})$, if we use the fact that $\overrightarrow{\text{RD}} \sqsubseteq \overrightarrow{\text{RD}}^\prime$, then we can deduce that said arbitrary element is also an element of the set $F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})^\prime$, and so $F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}}) \sqsubseteq F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})^\prime$. However, it seems to me that the textbook is very poorly written, and so it is difficult for me to even understand what said arbitrary elements of the set $F(\overrightarrow{\text{RD}})^\prime$ even are (they seem to be some kind of cartesian product, but I get very confused when trying to figure out precisely what they are). So how is it shown that $F$ is a monotone function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by giving a formula for the function $F$:
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\ent}{\mathsf{RD}_{\mathit{entry}}}
\newcommand{\ext}{\mathsf{RD}_{\mathit{exit}}}
\newcommand{\Lab}{\mathbf{Lab}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\by}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\bz}{\mathbf{z}}
&F(\ent(1),\ldots,\ent(6),\ext(1),\ldots,\ext(6)) =  \\
(&\{(\bx,?),(\by,?),(\bz,?)\}, \ext(1), \ext(2) \cup \ext(5), \ext(3), \ext(4), \ext(3), \\
&(\ent(1) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,1)\}, \\
&(\ent(2) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,2)\}, \\
&\ent(3), \\
&(\ent(4) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,4)\}, \\
&(\ent(5) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,5)\}, \\
&(\ent(6) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,6)\}).
\end{align*}
In order to show that $F$ is monotone, you need to show that the following hold whenever $\ent(i) \subseteq \ent'(i)$ and $\ext(i) \subseteq \ext'(i)$ for $i \in \{1,\ldots,6\}$:

- $\{(\bx,?),(\by,?),(\bz,?)\} \subseteq \{(\bx,?),(\by,?),(\bz,?)\}$.
- $\ext(1) \subseteq \ext'(1)$
- $\ext(2) \cup \ext(5) \subseteq \ext'(2) \cup \ext'(5)$
- $\ext(3) \subseteq \ext'(3)$
- $\ext(4) \subseteq \ext'(4)$
- $\ext(3) \subseteq \ext'(3)$
- $(\ent(1) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,1)\} \subseteq 
   (\ent'(1) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,1)\}$
- $(\ent(2) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,2)\} \subseteq (\ent'(2) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,2)\}$
- $\ent(3) \subseteq \ent'(3)$
- $(\ent(4) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,4)\} \subseteq (\ent'(4) \setminus \{(\bz,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(z,4)\}$
- $(\ent(5) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,5)\} \subseteq (\ent'(5) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,5)\}$
- $(\ent(6) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,6)\} \subseteq (\ent'(6) \setminus \{(\by,\ell) \mid \ell \in \Lab\}) \cup \{(y,6)\}$

I'm sure you can work it out.

Comment: This really clarifies what I need to do. And it's almost trivial. Thanks for the answer.